# Consuming WFC REST Webservice in Android

Tags: android, wcf, web-services

I just try to creating WCF REST Webservice for android
by following this tutorial http://fszlin.blogspot.com/2010/05/comsuming-wcf-services-with-android.html

But I get an error when I try to use JSONArray in Android.

```
JSONObject t = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
```

"A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of "testing""

I try to put character [ in the service method that I return the string ['testing']. but I doesnot work.

Any help would be appreciate
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because your WCF service doesn't return a Json Object or Array. It seems that it's returning just:
"testing" .
A valid json return value should be:
{"message":"Test Data"}
or 
[{"message":"TestingArray"}].

Please change your service to return something like that. Also you can use a JsonObject.ToString() to get a valid json string.